# Increment and decrement doesn't work

Tags: java

Why the result of this code is 0 and 1? Could someone explain this code?

How can change the result of condition: `if (b = !b)` between `true` or `false`?

Code:

```
public class Atomicity extends Thread {
    volatile static int i;
    boolean b;

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            if (b = !b) i++;
            else i--;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //new Atomicity().start();
        new Atomicity().start();

        while (true)
            System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While others already provided an answer, I'll try to explain in depth what's happening here.

When you do:

```
if(b = !b)
```

If `b` is `true`, the expression will be evaluated to `true` and the if condition will be met.

See the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26):

> At run-time, the result of **the assignment expression is the value of
>   the variable after the assignment has occurred**.

But in the next iteration, `b` will be `false`, then the condition won't be met because the assignment operator will return `false`.

It's worth mentioning that it's highly recommended to use `{` and `}` even for one line expressions.

Comment: thanks for your explanation. But if b = !b changes b from true to false and vice versa. Why in result i have  sequence 10 zero. and result is not -1 0  ?

Comment: @Mikhail Because `i` is switching between 1 and 0, one time the condition is met, the next iteration it's not.

Comment: ок. understand . Thanks

Comment: Why is it highly  recommended to use { and } even for one line expressions?

Comment: i saw the initially code on Integer class  and in method  public static String toString(int i, int radix) {

        if (radix < Character.MIN_RADIX || radix > Character.MAX_RADIX)
            radix = 10;

Comment: in this code its use without any { and }  for one line expressions

Comment: It's recommended because sometimes you may think you're inside a block but actually you're not. Just use them, it's more clear.

Answer (score 9):

`b = !b` changes `b` from `true` to `false` and vice versa.

`if (b = !b)` evaluates to `true` if `b` is assigned `true`.

Therefore running this condition is a loop alternates `b` from `false` to `true` and also alternates the result of the `if` condition.

Comment: thanks. i have not meet the expressions like (b = !b) before.

Answer (score 2):

You are using an assignment operator in your if statement:

```
if (b = !b) i++;
```

The expression

```
b = !b
```

contains the assignment operator (=) instead of a comparison (==). The assigment gives b a new value of !b and returns that new value.

Now the question is what you want to do. Your current code will keep switching the values of b. Of course using a comparison here would always return false (b == !b), so that is not useful either.

Comment: If he uses if (b == !b), it would be the same as if (false), which would be less interesting.